# Oracle Atomic Stored Procedure

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures

I am working on writing a stored procedure in Oracle that will refresh a table that contains denormalized data.  The outline of the procedure is:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE loadDenormalizedTable IS
BEGIN

DELETE FROM denormalizedTable;

INSERT INTO
    denormalizedTable
    (
        data
    )
SELECT DISTINCT
    data
FROM
    normalizedTables;

END;
/
```

I want all of this to happen in a transaction so that there will always be data in the table.  Right now the delete runs and the table is empty for a few minutes until the insert is finished.  What is the best way to handle this type of table refresh without having any down time?

Comment: The delete won't be visible to other sessions until you commit, which you shouldn't be doing inside the procedure. So you will see the empty table, but no-one else will. Is this a significantly cut-down version of your real procedure? Also... are you reinventing [materialized views](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25789/schemaob.htm#CFAIGHFC)?

Comment: Thanks!  The session issue tripped me up.  I see now that the data is still visible to the application while the table is being refreshed.  It is cut-down in that I removed all of the actual tables and columns and just put in placeholders.  The structure is the same though.  Yes, this is reinventing materialized views, the data architects are not a fan of MVs.

Comment: whats wrong with a mat view?  it can be refreshed atomically or non-atomically.  And once created, all this work can be reduced to a single refresh statement.  I won't say what I think of your data "architects"

Comment: I should have said that they are not a fan of MVs "for this project".  We do have MVs, so it's not a blanket opposition.  I don't know enough about what went in to the decision to comment either way about this specific issue, but I will say that in general these folks are excellent at what they do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, a procedure will execute as part of a larger transaction owned by the session. As the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/static.htm#i7105) mentions:

> **Note:**   A transaction can span multiple blocks, and a block can contain multiple transactions.

With your code as outlined, no other session will see your delete *or* insert until you commit after calling the procedure. If you just execute it from an SQL*Plus prompt for example:

```
SQL> exec loadDenormalizedTable;

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

... then anybody else looking at the table will still see the old data, even after both the delete and insert have completed. (Anyone else trying to execute the procedure, or insert or delete data in `denormalizedTable`, will block, but presumably you're only expecting others to be querying it). Once you issue a `commit` then everyone will see the same thing.

The only way to get the behaviour you describe is to manually end the transaction within the procedure:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE loadDenormalizedTable IS
BEGIN

DELETE FROM denormalizedTable;

COMMIT WORK; -- makes the delete visible elsewhere

INSERT INTO
    denormalizedTable
    (
        data
    )
SELECT DISTINCT
    data
FROM
    normalizedTables;    
END;
/
```

You do not not need to `commit` in the middle of the procedure, and it's very rare that you would or should ever want to do that as it breaks the atomicity.

It's possible you're doing something that does an implicit commit without you realising it; maybe calling another procedure or function that does its own commit (one of the reasons not to do that - it can have unexpected side-effects!), or perhaps a DDL statement - which will always do an implicit commit behind the scenes, but you'd have to be doing that with dynamic SQL anyway.

One other possibility is that you aren't actually doing a `delete`, but that you are doing a `truncate`. That would be visible to everyone else immediately, without an explicit commit, as hinted at [in the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/statements_10007.htm). That would also be a significant departure from the outline you provided though.

Comment: I'm still getting used to the way sessions work in Oracle.  It is working exactly as you described.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If Oracle partitioning option is available, the best, and most efficient way to do it is to use the partition swapping operation. This is a very common operation done in many massive data warehouses.

See some examples at:

http://www.akadia.com/services/ora_exchange_partition.html
http://gerardnico.com/wiki/database/oracle/partition_exchange_loading

For instance you could imagine having a second table with the same exact structure as denormalizedTable. To implement your load operation:

- truncate denormalizedTable2
- insert your data into denormalizeTable2
- exchange the partition of tables denormalizedTable and denormalizedTable2

It usually guarantees a minimal impact on the running application.

Comment: Thanks.  I will keep this in mind if the DBAs prefer a truncate vs a delete.